# Android installation in a mobile

Tags: android, mobile, installation

Is it possible to install Android in a normal mobile phone?

I have Sony Ericsson [Naite](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_naite-2818.php) which has only key pad interface (No touch). I would like to install Android in my phone for experimenting with it. It will be great if its possible to dual boot Android with Symbian :-).

Do we need any other special hardware to install operating system in a mobile phone? Will Android work on a key-pad mobile?

Any pointer/suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Naite is a fairly simple handset running on the Sony Ericsson JP8 platform.

End users are not supposed to be able to update the firmware on the phone.

Only Sony-Ericsson partners are supposed to get the PC software to update the firmware and only Sony-Ericsson is supposed to be able to create new firmwares.

(maybe you can hack the phone so you get it to boot on android or symbian but that's going to be unsupported behavior that nobody will guarantee)

If you want to experiment with creating your own android firmwares, I suggest buying an ADP2 handset from google.

If you want to experiment with creating your own Symbian firmwares, I suggest buying a Texas Instrument Zoom 2 device since it is the reference platform for Symbian.

The Zoom 2 seems to also support Android, by the way.

If you just want to experiment with application development on both platforms, I suggest using the two SDKs and emulators first.

There are some pretty cheap Symbian phones out there, particularly in the Series60 3rd edition range and, depending on where you live, you might even be able to find a Pay-As-You-Go Android phone like the Pulse.

Answer (score 0):

I **STRONGLY** encourage you to go visit the [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/index.php) and visit their Android sections for this kind of information.

Comment: it should be possible, i also saw a blog where somebody installed Android on the IPhone.

Comment: The iphone is a totally different devices than this. The iphone already uses linux (OSX is similar to linux) so you're starting from a totally different point.